# CSS for first td of each tr in certain table

Tags: html, css

I have table with id "student".
e.g.

```
 <table id="student">
    <tr>
        <td>Role</td>
        <td>Merin</td>
        <td>Nakarmi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Role</td>
        <td>Tchelen</td>
        <td>Lilian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Role</td>
        <td>Suraj</td>
        <td>Shrestha</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For each row in this table, the first `<td>` has value Role and I want to hide this first `<td>` for every row. 
I tried option like

```
#student > tr > td:first-child
{ 
    width: 0px; important;
}
```

But unfortunately did not work.

Please help

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use the below.

```
table#student tr td:first-child{display:none;}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6HwLb/)**

Comment: For you Nathan. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090764/css-for-hiding-multiple-columns-in-a-table

Comment: Answered - @MerinNakarmi

Answer (score 2):

Your this code is not correct:

```
{ width: 0px; important; }
```

this should be:

```
#student > tr > td:first-child{ 
  width: 0px !important; 
}
```

before `important`  property you are using semicolon which is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #student > tr > td:first-child{
  display : none;
    }
```