# JQuery hide table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, show-hide

I am trying to hide a specific column of html table after it's contents are loaded.
Table html is created dynamically and loaded with JQuery. This part works as expected.

```js
let cur_grid = document.getElementById('grid1')
// table html is created.
let str_tbl_html = '<table id="tbl_grid1"><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></tbody></table>'
$.when($(cur_grid).html(str_tbl_html)).done(function() {
  console.log('hide 3rd column')
  $('#tbl_grid1 tr td:nth-child(3)').hide()
  // also tried
  $('#tbl_grid1').find('td:nth-child(3)').hide()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='grid1'></div>
```

I don't get any errors but 3rd column is not hidden.

Comment: `let cur_grid = document.getElementById('grid1')` Your ID is just `grid1`

Comment: Maybe try putting the code `$('#tbl_grid1 tr td:nth-child(3)').hide()` inside a `setTimout()`? without any time specified (or) just 100ms.

Comment: Also when using css to hide it no need to worry about timing https://stackoverflow.com/a/20090968/10634638

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine. Maybe you should post a  a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: Do you get the `console.log("hide 3rd col")`?

Comment: @freedomn-m. I do

Comment: This isn't asynchronous `$.when($(cur_grid).html(str_tbl_html))` - do you have something different in your "real" code?

Comment: @freedomn-m. The only difference is that grid1 is dynamic value.

Comment: I've added an actual table to your sample (which some earlier converted to a snippet).  The snippet is meant to *demonstrate* the problem - as you can now see, there's no problem and your code, as provided,works fine.

Comment: *"grid1 is dynamic value"* - which bit is grid1?   `str_tbl_html`?  `cur_grid`?

Comment: @freedomn-m I am trying to develop a generic grid/table that displays different data based on where it's call from. So on my html pages i have a grid with unique id and table associated with that. I create/fill table dynamically with ajax call. But sometimes i need to hide/show columns

Comment: That's cool, but if you already have the html in `str_tbl_html` then the `$.when` part isn't needed.  Perhaps how you populate `str_tbl_html` needs the `$.when` part if that's retrieved via ajax - so maybe the code inside the `$.when` in your "real" code is running before `str_tbl_html` has been populated, giving you appearance that the column is not being hidden (because it hasn't been rendered yet).   Hard to tell, you'll need to update the code in the question to *demonstrate* the issue as the code provided works fine.

Comment: I think you need to review how jQuery Deferreds and Promises work. Your Deferred seems to be immediately resolving after the .html command, whether the new elements have been drawn to the DOM or not, which is why the timing works for some people and not for others. At this point using setTimeout as Jones Joseph suggested is a quick fix, then look up "how to determine when an element is appended to the DOM" for more complete answers.

Comment: @tlong314. SetTimeout did the trick. I think i worngly assumed that .done only executes when html is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't trust Deferreds to determine when DOM elements have been drawn to the screen. Since you are using `let` I assume you can use modern JavaScript like `onanimationstart`. You can use this with CSS animations to determine when the table has actually been drawn.

```css
@keyframes any-animation {
  from {opacity: 0.99;}
  to {opacity: 1.0;}
}

table {
  animation-name: any-animation;
  animation-duration: 0.001s;
}
```

```js
let cur_grid = document.getElementById('grid1')

// table html is created.
let str_tbl_html = '<table id="tbl_grid1" onanimationstart="hideThirdColumn()"><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></tbody></table>'

function hideThirdColumn() {
  $('#tbl_grid1 tr td:nth-child(3)').hide()
};
```

I learned this trick on an old blog post on [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/media-query-change-detection-in-javascript-through-css-animations/) (he credits a few other bloggers on that page as well).