# How to hide one cell in the ASCIIDOC table?

Tags: cell, hide, asciidoc

I have a table with human parameters. I want to hide one column, for example age, if attribute :showall: is not set. How to do that? I can hide only the whole table, but not the one column.

```
.Human parameters
:showall:
ifdef::showall[]
[cols="1,1,1,1,1"]
|===
|Name
|Sex
|Age
|Country
|Weight


5+^|Values


|John Daw
|Male
|41
|Algeria
|85
endif::showall[]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a built in feature.

You have two options:

1. For cell content that should be hidden, simply remove it from the table.
2. If you need show/hide functionality, you'll need to add some custom JavaScript and CSS to make that happen.

For option 2, the technique for including JS/CSS is called [Docinfo files](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor/latest/docinfo/).

You'll have to experiment with column show/hide, as there may be browser compatibility or presentation issues that would need to be addressed. That said, this answer might show a technique that would work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34098320/4023764

Comment: From the nature of the example table, I suspect that the reason to hide the column is that it is sensitive. In that case, it may not be enough to use a JS/CSS solution. The data is still in the generated HTML and can be accessed by the client, who may not be entitled to it, even though the display does not show it.

I do not know how security savvy the person asking is, but it is essential to be aware that the JS/CSS solution may not be ok in case of CID issues.