# How to hide or show a html table column

Tags: php, html

I'm new to php and I'm trying to make a html page using php, html, css and js
in this page there is one big table with many rows and columns and I want to hide or show only those columns which the user wants  I tried this using if loop but its not working properly for me Please help

```
if($column != "Select"){
    echo "<td class=\"column $color\" name=\"".$name_column[$i]->name."\" field=\"".$text."\" orig_value=\"".$name_column[$i]->$text."\">".format_data($name_column[$i]->$text,$format)."</td>";
}
```

when I run this code using this if loop it doesn't print the values in the row but it prints the row without value.

When the column != Select this is the output

[image]

When the column == Select this is the output

[image]

But I want that the column should completely hide not just the values in the row

Comment: The title says you're trying to hide a column, not the whole row. If you want to hide a row, put the `<tr>` and `</tr>` inside the `if`.

Comment: I' trying to hide the column and not row 

Comment: Then the rest of the row is supposed to appear.

Comment: If you are just showing/hiding you can do this pretty easily in CSS with the [`nth-child` selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20090868/231316), no PHP needed

Comment: Note that different rows will have different numbers of columns if you do this. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Barmar yes the rest of the row should appear

Comment: You should also remove the column from the heading row of the table.

Comment: no they have same number of columns @Barmar

Comment: the heading should also be removed

Comment: My earlier comment about different numbers was when the code used `$row`, not `$column`.

Comment: Please show all the code that creates the table. It's hard to see how these variables are being set.

Comment: ohh...I changed that coz I though there might be some confusion btw rows and columns 

Comment: Not related to your problem (at least directly), but `$name_column[$i]->$text` is probably wrong, and instead you want `$name_column[$i]->text`

Comment: actually its a script of 4000 lines  and this line is used for creating 1 column if 
 we comment out this line in the script then this column is not visible in the table @Barmar

Comment: thankss...let me give it a try @ChrisHaas

Comment: We don't need all 4,000 lines, just a [mre].

Comment: This looks like the correct code for the column. Do you have a loop for creating the column headings? You need similar logic there.

Comment: yes there's id a different loop for creating the headings and its working fine when I try to hide the column ` $scount = 1;
if($column1!=Select)
{
        $scount = $scount+2;
}if($column2!=Select){
$scount = $scount+2;
}
if($column3!=Select)
{
        $scount = $scount+2;
}if($column4!=Select){
$scount = $scount+2;
}

if($column5!=Select)
{
        $scount = $scount+2;
}if($coumn6!=Select){
$scount = $scount+2;
}
if($column7!=Select){
$scount = $scount+2;
}`
`echo "<td colspan=$scount></td>";`

Comment: That doesn't leave out the `Column` heading, it just changes some column's width so it covers two columns. That's why I want to see the code in context, and with readable formatting. [

Comment: You can make yourself "library" creating your html table it takes some time but it's better and also more pleasant than this kind of code. I myself do have one, can't share it unfortunately. Give it like 8-12 hours and you will have fully customized autogenerated table